# htaccess rule for blocking domain and subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to block users using "hidemyass" from viewing a site, they typically come in with the referring domains similar to this:

- hidemyass.com/
- 3.hidemyass.com/ip-3/encoded/&f=norefer
- 2.hidemyass.com/ip-2/encoded/&f=norefer

**My question is:**

How would I block all referring users that have come from hidemyass.com and the subdomains using a htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

With apache( if you're suing that) it's pretty simple. Just try the following in the htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (hidemyass) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (whaterverelse) [NC]        
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

I'm not sure you want to block only hidemyass so I am giving you the code for multiple referrers. If you're not using apache we need to know something more...